# How to edit file online which is saved on Azure Storage

Tags: asp.net, azure, office365api

I am saving files on Azure file storage. I want to update these files online from my web application. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Take the tour here https://stackoverflow.com/tour it will help show you how to ask questions in the correct way

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score -1):

You need to build a suitable application either Web based or Desktop based. All the crud operations you can perform via accessing the APIs of Blob.

You can refer Azure Storage Sample Repository for get complete understanding about how to perform each tasks with blobs. Ex: Append, Copy, Delete Blobs etc..

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-samples-dotnet

Also refer following links for additional information.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/storage-blob-dotnet-getting-started

Comment: I have already done that. I am using Azure File Storage API to upload documents on Azure Storage. Now I want to edit these documents online from my webapp using something like Office 365 online.